# Different variable address between g++ -std=c++11 and visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, g++, memory-address

When running this code

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    char b;
    char c;
    printf("%d\n", &b - &c);
    return 0;
}
```

I got `12` using Microsoft visual studio 2013, and `-1` using `g++ -std=c++11` under Ubuntu 14.04. What is the reason for this difference?

Or did I make a mistake when testing variables' memory addresses?

Comment: Run the on the same machine more than once. You might get different value then as well.

Comment: Not sure why the question is tagged for c++11

Comment: @Jagannath I am a rookie, could you please explain why I might get different value running on the same machine more than once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually implementation specific. For the given code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    char b;
    char c;
    printf("%p %p %u\n", &b, &c, &b - &c);
    return 0;
}
```

GCC and MinGW gave an output of 1 for me. Judging by the values of &b and &c, we can say that memory was allocated continuously for two chars b and c. However, other compilers like VS-2013 and Intel C++ compiler will give some other values depending on how the allocation of memory is done.

Comment: Exactly. While, even the plus-minus of the result is different, does it mean that the alignment orient of memory location are different? Since I got `12` from VS-2013, I am wondering what kind of data may fill the memory.

Comment: @stanleyerror, the when the compiled program is loaded into memory, it generally searches random locations in the memory for allocating spaces to variables (for some of the implementations). so, yes thats possible